# Trying to get the column size of a column using jdbc metadata

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I am trying to recreate a schema for a table using only the metadata from jdbc.

I have it all working except for the column size eg. location VARCHAR(10)

Currently for every column it is printing VARCHAR(2000000000)

The code:

```
ResultSet rs = databaseMetaData.getColumns(null, null, tableName, null);
while(rs.next()) {
  int columnSize = rs.getInt("COLUMN_SIZE");
}
```

The expected output is the number used when creating the table that is in the schema but it always returns 2000000000. Is there something simple I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tags of your question indicate that you are using SQLite.

The [documentation](http://sqlite.org/datatype3.html), chapter 2.2 Affinity Name Examples, states:

> Note that numeric arguments in parentheses that following the type
>   name (ex: "VARCHAR(255)") are ignored by SQLite - SQLite does not
>   impose any length restrictions (other than the large global
>   SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH limit) on the length of strings, BLOBs or numeric
>   values.

Since SQLite doesn't use the length information, for COLUMN_SIZE it simply returns the maximum size of character based columns.

Comment: Why does the number I get not equal the SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH then?

Comment: @hysteriaistic don't know. The Xerial JDBC driver simply contains a hardcoded number: https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/blob/master/src/main/java/org/sqlite/jdbc3/JDBC3DatabaseMetaData.java#L1144. You could raise an issue in that project.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the method

```
databaseMetaData.getColumnDisplaySize(int column)
```

where the `column` parameter is the number of column in the table. Source: 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html